# Error in compiling an anchor program

Tags: anchor, rust

I am trying to compile my anchor code that I wrote , but it says info is undeclared lifetime. I want to understand why the error is occurring , will be attaching the code along with it as well as the error.

````
declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod prokect {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
    ctx.accounts.new_account.data = 0; // Message will show up in the tx logs
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn increment(ctx:Context<Increment>) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.inc.data += 1;
        Ok(())
    }
    
    pub fn decrement(ctx:Context<Decrement>) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.dec.data -= 1;
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn set_value(ctx:Context<SetValue>,data:u64) -> Result<()> {
       // require!(data < 100, CounterError::DataTooLarge);
       // require!(data > 0, CounterError::DataTooSmall);
        ctx.accounts.set.data = data;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Decrement<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub dec: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Increment<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub inc: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SetValue<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub set: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
}


#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    data: u64
}```


ERROR
**
programs/prokect/src/lib.rs:35:33
   |
30 | pub struct Initialize {
   |                      - help: consider introducing lifetime `'info` here: `<'info>`
...
35 |     pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
   |                                 ^^^^^ undeclared lifetime
   |
   = help: if you want to experiment with in-band lifetime bindings, add `#![feature(in_band_lifetimes)]` to the crate attributes
**
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a `<'info>` for your Initialize accounts struct.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize <'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```